# Есть некоторый код Python который создаёт сервер с помощью unicorn берёт шаблон html,но не может найти css

Tags: python, html, css, веб-сервер, uvicorn

Есть некоторый код Python который создаёт сервер с помощью unicorn берёт шаблон html,но не может найти css

В этом коде я читаю и отображаю html шаблон,выводит без всяких проблем,но он не выводит css стили,которые я задал в отдельном файле для данного шаблон.
В html шаблоне все связанно и если запускать шаблон просто в браузере,он выводится со всеми стилями.
Сервер выводит ошибку "INFO:     127.0.0.1:49805 - "GET /css/login_style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found" Я понимаю,что сервер не может найти файл по данному пути,хотя он там есть и я вот не могу никак понять,как мне достучаться до нужного css файла

Также думаю стоит добавить,что python сервер находится в основной папке,внутри основной папки есть папка html,там он берёт html шаблон,а уже в папке html есть папка css

```
@app.get('/')  # Метод, который запускается когда приходит запрос GET на корневую страницу "/"
def index_page(username: Optional[str] = Cookie(default=None)):
    with open('html/login_page.html', "r") as f:
        login_page = f.read()
    if not username:
        return Response(login_page, media_type='text/html')
    valid_username = get_username_from_signed_str(username)
    if not valid_username:
        response = Response(login_page, media_type='text/html')
        response.delete_cookie(key='username')
        return response

    try:
        user = users[valid_username]
    except KeyError:
        response = Response(login_page, media_type='text/html')
        response.delete_cookie(key='username')
        return response
    return Response(f'Привет, {users[valid_username]["name"]} <br />'
                    f'Ваш баланс: {users[valid_username]["balance"]} евро'
                    , media_type='text/html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, в качестве фреймворка для веб-сервера вы используете Flask. Всё верно, Вы можете открыть страницу html, т.к. возвращаете её в ответе для корневой страницы. Чтобы добавить статические файлы в проект, такие как `.js`, `.html`, `.css`, Вам нужно сделать действия, которые указаны в документации Flask в разделе **Static files** https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#static-files

Comment: Я пользуюсь FastAPI

Comment: Но посыл я понял,спасибо
Попробую исправить)

Comment: Прошу прощения, никогда не юзал Python для бэкенда. Для FastAPI в документации есть такое решение: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/?h=sta